# KinectBackgroundRemoval180_32/64.dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, kinect

I was reading the example from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/10/22/using-kinect-background-removal-with-multiple-users.aspx), I see the project contains two background removal dlls, one for 32 bit computers and one for 64 bit computers. However they are not listed in the References.

[image: reference]

My question is what does the small blue icon mean at the lower right corner of the dll icon, and what is the proper way to use these two dlls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small blue icon means that the dll is a link.  It was added using the "add as link" option in the Add dialog box.  It means it is not a literal file in your project, but a link to a file that is somewhere else.  You can use this feature to share a file across two projects, or to add a file to your project while keeping it stored somewhere external.  You can see what this does if you right-click on it and select properties the properties window will appear.  Take a look at "Full Path" and you will see where the file is.  Compare that to another file in your project and notice that the path points to right there within your project.

The DLL files are the  "native" DLLs, and they will automatically be used by Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.BackgroundRemoval.dll, which you already have a reference to.  The only thing you have to do is make sure that those DLL files are in the same directory as your EXE.  That should happen automatically since they are in your project, and the properties for those files are configured as "Copy Local" = Newest.

Comment: Updated my answer to include what the DLL files are for.